# Canvas is not storing drawing with background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I am working on a tool that takes the images, allows users to draw on it and save.

Whats working: Taking image as background, drawing on it

Whats not working: saving whole canvas..
I just stores the drawing only not drawing along with image.

I went through stack but couldnt find solution working for me.

```
<canvas id="drawtool" width="800" height="300" style="background:url(image/test.png) no-repeat center center"></canvas>
```

and the JS to drawimage is

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('drawtool');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
   };
```

Edited: I already tried

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('drawtool');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var imageObj = new Image();
 imageObj.src = "image/test.png"; 
 imageObj.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
};
```

but It shows the image on canvas for some time and as I click on canvas to draw, the image gets disappeared.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here’s how you can draw on an image.

I set the opacity of the image lower so you can see the user’s drawing better.

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/6eYEz/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var lastX;
    var lastY;
    var strokeColor="red";
    var strokeWidth=2;
    var canMouseX;
    var canMouseY;
    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var isMouseDown=false;
    var imageObj=new Image();
    imageObj.onload=function(){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.globalAlpha=.3;
        ctx.drawImage(this,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.restore();
    }
    imageObj.src="http://www.proquestk12.com/widgets/images/WorldRegion_worldmap.gif";


    function handleMouseDown(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      lastX=canMouseX;
      lastY=canMouseY;
      isMouseDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseup stuff here
      isMouseDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseOut stuff here
      isMouseDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousemove stuff here
      if(isMouseDown){
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.lineWidth=5;
          ctx.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
          ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY);
          ctx.lineTo(canMouseX,canMouseY);
          ctx.stroke();     
          lastX=canMouseX;
          lastY=canMouseY;
      }
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width=576 height=307></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the background image on it, all you need to do is set the src of imageObj to that file. It'd look like this(after you declare and define imageObj):

```
imageObj.src="image/test.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<canvas id="drawtool" width="800" height="300" ></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('drawtool');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src="image/test.png";
imageObj.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(this, 0, 0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
```

Comment: @ MJQ I already tried that, its working for a while but as I clicks on canvas for drawing, image gets disappeared. P.S. I am taking the URL of image dynamically

Comment: That should be happening due to some other reason! The code above is the basic code and should work perfectly! Here is working example, http://jsfiddle.net/4mLt9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your image doesn't have its src property. Also, it is useless and misleading to give a background image via CSS to your canvas, because the image isn't actually on it and that's why you didn't find your bug :)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('drawtool');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = "image/test.png";
imageObj.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
};
```